# How to use Less variables in CSS

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, variables, less

Ok, so I am not new to using Bootstrap, but I am new to customizing it and using the LESS variables. I am trying to do the simplest of things just to check to see if the LESS variables are even working.

I am trying to set the body's background-color to @brand-success just to test it. It is not working. Chrome tells me that it is an invalid property value.

I know that I've used LESS variables from Bootstrap in jQuery before, but I thought that the CSS file worked in the same way.

I'm not sure if it makes any difference but I am using the bootstrap.css file locally instead of linking it from an external sever like I do the jQuery files.

I don't know if this is a duplicate question or not. I tried my best to search for the answer but the questions were all seemingly different than mine.

Comment: it doesn't work that way. you can use it in less files. but not in css files.

Comment: do you know of a good resource to learn how to do that. I found a youtube video but I want to make sure that it is accurate @sanjithedward

Comment: like maybe http://lesscss.org/ ?

Comment: Did you edit the variables.less file? You probably just need to compile it... check out gulp http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/06/11/building-with-gulp/. The variable syntax for less for colors should be like `@brand-success: #45ADFF;`

Comment: Sure the official less website offers a lot of examples and ways to do it. But, i dont think you can include them in css because css is a stylesheet and not a programming language or atleast a preprocessor

Comment: I just know that I used to use the Bootstrap LESS variables in jQuery and php. I only assumed that they'd work out of the box in CSS as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Less is a CSS *pre-processor*. You can use pure CSS in Less, so CSS *is* less, but the opposite is not true. Chrome has no idea what Less is. It only interprets CSS. `@brand-sucess` is not valid CSS.

It may have worked in PHP because probably your PHP application previously ran a less pre-processor *before* sending the CSS file to the client.

It may have worked in JQuery if you are using a client-side Less pre-processor. In this case, you *can* send LESS directly to the client, but first it must be transformed into a real CSS color (ex: #58fe23) before Chrome can do anything with it.